# Creating small polarised scientific lenses?

Tags: optics, reflection, polarization, lenses, optical-materials

How would I go about creating small polarised scientific lenses?

Thinking 5mm by 5mm, with a light-source behind it for the purposes of reducing (polarised) surface reflection (assisted with a cross-polarised viewer).

Is the idea that I just need to apply magnesium fluoride; and if so, at what consistency and against what type of lens?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're aiming for but magnesium fluoride ${\rm Mg\, F_2}$ won't polarise light in the way I think you're aiming for. It is very slightly birefringent, so a very thick coating will convert throughgoing linearly polarised light to circularly polarised, but will not attenuate one polarisation. You'll need to lay down a polaroid layer for that.

For reflected light: any combination of layers in any dielectic multilayer coating does not show a polarisation preference when the light is incident normally to the surface (there is no difference between the relationship between field and surface for an S and P waves). Again, thick birefringent layers can alter the polarisation state of the reflected light just as a waveplate does, but they will not preferentially attenuate one polarisation.

Only when the reflexion is non-normal do the S and P waves have different reflexion co-efficients. If you are imaging in a position such that only light of a narrow angular range reaches your imager, then you can set the system up so that only reflexions from light incident near the Brewster angle reach your imager. This effect arises whether or not you use ${\rm Mg\, F_2}$ coatings. An ${\rm Mg\, F_2}$ coating will enhance the effect by lowering the reflected power of both polarisations. For example, here is the reflexion co-efficient as a function of indidence angle at 55nm wavelength for uncoated N-BK7 glass:

[image: Uncoated N-BK7 at 550nm Wavelength]

and here is the same plot for N-BK7 coated with a quarter wavelength thick ($550 / (4 \times 1.37 = 100{\rm nm}$ thick ${\rm Mg\, F_2}$) coating. If you image near to the Brewster angle of 55 degrees, you'll get mainly S-polarised reflexions.

[image: N-BK7 with 100nm thick MgF2 coating at 550nm wavelength]

Complicated multilayers can widen the trough around the Brewster null, so you can indeed attenuate quite wide angles P polarised reflexion. However, this is not a simple laboratory exercise. Depending on what you need, you may need to have a specialised coating designed for you and manufactured by a specialist manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at buying an [Achromatic Lens](http://www.edmundoptics.com/optics/optical-lenses/achromatic-lenses/vis-0-coated-achromatic-lenses/47652)… I am attempting to setup a polarised light source to reduce reflections against skin when imaging.

Comment: @AT Are you trying to build something like a miniaturized dermatoscope?

Comment: @AT Are you aware of ThorLabs - depending on the shape you need for your prototype, you can build a small 13mm diameter system with a pellicule-kind of polarizer (or even polarizing beamsplitter) with their SM05 small tube systems. Depending on your imaging mode, you are going to be dealing mainly paraxial waves, so that any polarization preference for a nonpolarising layer is going to be very small. So you're going to need either a polaroid or polarizing beamsplitter somewhere in lighting system.

Comment: Thanks Rod, yes I am looking to build something miniaturized  dermatoscope related. Will investigate what you are talking about further.